# Inline Select with text using Bootstrap v4

Tags: css, dropdown, bootstrap-4

I am looking for an inline dropdown like the following using Bootstrap v4 :

[image]

I tried many cases, and the closest one until now is :

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem as you see ,the toggler should not be a button , it might be span .. Which css rules that we need to add it to reach something like in the screencast above.

Comment: Ah !  You are right @Blazemonger .

Comment: The dropdown is triggered by any element using `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Answer (score 1):

Got it !

- Add `d-inline-flex` to the container.
- Change button by span  & remove btn class & add `font-weight-bold` class.

  ```
    <div class="dropdown d-inline-flex">
      Show me posts by: <span class="dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold"id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </span>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown open is triggered by *any* element using `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

https://www.codeply.com/go/oYI9nZEWBy

```
  <h4 data-toggle="dropdown">
        Open Dropdown
  </h4>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
           ...
       </a>
  </ul>
```